# Flutter get data that was returned to Drawer from Navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter

I have the main/homepage widget of my app, let's call it `home.dart`.

Inside this widget, I have defined the drawer key in my `Scaffold` widget. The code for the `Drawer` object is in a separate file, `navdrawer.dart`.

**home.dart**

```
import 'navdrawer.dart';
. . .
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      ...
```

Now inside `NavDrawer`, I construct my `Drawer` widget which has a *settings* button, which links to the `settings.dart` screen.

Which I do like this:

**navdrawer.dart**

```
. . .
InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                final result = await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()),
                );
                print(result);
              },
              child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.settings,
                    color: AppTextColor,
                  ),
                  title: Text('Settings'))),
```

So now, when the user presses the back button on the settings page, the `Navigator.pop()` call will return the data I need to the `result` variable in `navdrawer.dart`.

But my problem is ... how do I get this data to my `home.dart` screen/state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use `provider`, `scoped_model` or other state management techniques for this. The easiest (but also the worthless) solution would be to use a global variable.

However, there's a middle ground. For simplicity I'm using `dynamic` for the type of result, you'd better know what `Settings` return, so use that type instead.

Your `home.dart` file

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  dynamic _result; // Create a variable. 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavDrawer(
        onResult: (result) {
          _result = result; // <-- This is your result. 
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Add following in your `navdrawer.dart`:

```dart
class NavDrawer extends StatelessWidget {

  // Add these two lines. 
  final ValueChanged onResult; 
  NavDrawer({this.onResult}); 

  // Other code ...

}
```

Modify your `onTap` method inside `navdrawer.dart` file:

```dart
onTap: () async {
  final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()),
  );
  onResult(result); // <-- Add this line. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set parameters into the pop method.
Like

```
Navigator.pop(context,true)
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get those values to my homepage screen/widget?

Answer (score 0):

Define 'Static'  global variable in homepage screen/widget
Then call the variable from anywhere :

1- homepage :

```
Static String getData;
```

2- when returned to Drawer :

```
homepage.getData=value;
Navigator.pop();
```